# Get html and headers from single request using Python

Tags: python, urllib2, httpconnection

I'm investigating the possibility of making a single http request using python to retrieve both the html as well as http headers info instead of having to make 2 seperate calls.

Anyone know of any good ways?

Also what is the performance differences between the different methods of making these requests, e.g. urllib2 and httpconnection, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `urllib2.urlopen()`. The HTML can be retrieved by calling the `read()` method of the returned object, and the headers are available in the `headers` attribute.

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')

>>> print f.headers
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:57:25 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close

>>> print f.read()
<!doctype html><html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [HTTPResponse](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/httpresponse-objects.html) you can the headers and the content with two function calls, but it doesn't make two trips to the server.